# Filezilla 227 Entering Passive Mode

Tags: web-hosting, ftp

I started to transfer some plugin files to my server via Filezilla. After a while I'm getting following error from my server.

```
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (185,22,186,185,237,198)
Command:    STOR text.js
Error:  Data connection could not be established: ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt time out.
```

How can I fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to transfer that error message into English if you wish to get help here.

Comment: Right. I translated error message into English.

Comment: "After a while" - are you able to transfer anything?

Comment: No connection brokes and I can't upload anything until close Filezilla and re-connect to server.